# Change link color for an element in a javascript map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, hyperlink

I would like to change the link color in a javascript google maps tooltip window.
By default the map uses the "a/" preference but I want to use an own color for this link.

I tried to add a class to the link so i can change the color in CSS but without any success. Do you have any idea, how to change to following code, so i can add a css class to it? Or do you have another idea, how to change the color of the link?

```js
var content_title = title;
   if ( link ) {
    content_title = $( '<div/>' ).append( $( "<a/>" ).attr( 'href', link ).text( title ) ).html();
    
   }
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue (in the question)

Comment: Can you try using `<span>` on the hyperlink and then adding inline style to it?

Answer (score 0):

I insert a google map on my website via a plugin. This plugin uses a default google map with some own content. I want to customize a specific element inside the info window, when you click the marker on the map. It's the title of an event which is also a link.
At the moment the content of the info window looks like this:

```js
marker = new google.maps.Marker( marker );

   var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

   var content_title = title;
   if ( link ) {
    content_title = $( '<div/>' ).append( $( "<a/>" ).attr( 'href', link ).text( title ) ).html();
    
   }
   
   
   var content = content_title;

   if ( address ) {
    content = content + "<br/>" + address;
   }

   infoWindow.setContent( content );

   google.maps.event.addListener( marker, 'click', function( event ) {
    infoWindow.open( tg.map, marker );
   } );

   tg.markers.push( marker );

   if ( tg.refine ) {
    marker.setVisible( false );
   }
   tg.bounds.extend( myLatlng );
  }
 } );
```

the element "var content_title = title;" is a link using the default link specification of my theme. I would like to change the color of this link. I thought the best way would be just to give this element a class name so I can change the color in CSS. I tried following code:

```js
var content_title = title;
   if ( link ) {
    content_title = $( '<div/>' ).addClass( "myClass" ).append( $( "<a/>" ).attr( 'href', link ).text( title ) ).html();
    
   }
```

I hope now it's clearer what I want to do.
I am happy for some help.